# JS error: unable to get value of property 0: object is null or undefined

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011

I am writing this JS for CRM 2011, and this error pops out whenever I choose a value for account field for the FIRST time.  If I close the popup window, the program actually works fine, and if I reset the value for this account field, no error occurs and everything is good, too.

Any ideas what's going on?  And what exactly is property 0?  I tried some alert, but I can't seem to find where in the code is causing this problem.

Thanks

Comment: Could you please show us your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stupid question... The reason why I didn't catch my mistake was I used the wrong expression to do the alerts.  Anyways, a method that should be executed got executed, so a null check solves it.